# How to run Spring boot web application through Java Webstart?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-web-start

We are able to build & run **spring boot** standalone web application through *Java Runtime Environment*. We are ambitious enough to run it through **Java Web start**. Regarding to the issue we are able to develop an web application and signed all it's dependencies and itself. After that host all of the dependencies to [jws.chorke.com](http://jws.chorke.com/). Finally we are able to run it but unable to access all the classpath resources/static resources from browser. Here is the static resources dir structure as following:

```
/dev/cki/chorke─ebis─server
    ├─ src/main/java/
    └─ src/main/resources/
        └─ META-INF/resources/static/
            ├─ fonts/
            ├─ icons/
            ├─ images/
            ├─ logos/
            ├─ Ext-all.js
            ├─ favicon.ico
            ├─ glyphicons.css
            ├─ Bis-all.css
            ├─ Log-all.css
            ├─ Bis-all.js
            ├─ Log-all.js
            ├─ sencha.css
            ├─ Cki.css
            └─ Cki.js
```

Lets say the web appliction runs on **8018**, it's contextPath is **ebis** and we could get access of its by [localhost:8018/ebis/bd/en](http://localhost:8018/ebis/bd/en) but unable to get access it's static resources for example [localhost:8018/ebis/static/favicon.ico](http://localhost:8018/ebis/static/favicon.ico).
Do you have any hacks regarding to the issue?

Comment: [How about packaging it as a normal war project and deploying on Java Webstart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870764/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-as-a-war-file-on-a-dedicated-tomcat-is-not-w/33893109#33893109)

Comment: It's a regular jar file with lots of dependencies and embedded tomcat server. It's suppose to me there is a problem on **spring boot class loader** which one unable to load the resources

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: This project was postponed. You will be updated if this project resume.